# Use an application automatically

Tags: applications

Is it possible to first automatically open an application and then automatically click on a few buttons within that app ? Is creating such a profile possible?

Comment: You should​ try Tasker

Answer (score 0):

There is app called automate which probably achieve what ur saying like following examples like

- sending message on specific app is running, when like battery percent is n% then do this, etc.

[More description on there website](http://llamalab.com/automate/)

Answer (score 0):

[Require root]use this[app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro) it's records your touchs and play it as you want like speed and times of cycle